# how can i convert my array data into comma separated string

Tags: angular

In below onButtonClick there is Ids variable i want to call only that data in my hubxCategoryId  formcontrol. and i want to show the data as a comma separeted string

```
   onButtonClick(value:any,categoryIds:number, index:number):any{
        debugger
        const formArray = this.patientReportForm.get("hubxCategoryId") as FormArray;
        var x = formArray.controls.find(x => x.get('catId').value === categoryIds )
        var currentindex = formArray.controls.indexOf(x);   
        ((this.patientReportForm.get('hubxCategoryId') as FormArray).at(currentindex) as FormGroup).get('categoryId').patchValue(value) ; 

let Ids : Array<any> = []; 
    formArray.value.forEach( (item) => {
      Ids.push(item.categoryId)
    })

    return Ids
    
    }
```

This is my formcontrol .I want to call Ids in HubxCategoryId

```
this.patientReportForm = new FormGroup({
      patientId : new FormControl(Number(this.clientId)),
      hubxCategoryId : this.formBuilder.array([]),
      notes : new FormControl(),
    })
```

**array is printing from here**

```
getHubxReport() {
    //debugger
    this.usersService.getHubxReport(this.clientId).subscribe((response: ResponseModel) => {
      if (response != null && response.data != null && response.data.length > 0) {
        this.hubxReportList = response.data;
        const formArray = this.patientReportForm.get("hubxCategoryId") as FormArray;
        response.data.forEach(item => {
        formArray.push(this.formBuilder.group({
          catId: item.categoryId,
          categoryId:[]
          }))
       // })
      })
      }
    }
    );
   
  }
```

Comment: Q: Have you successfully extracted the numbers you wanted from your data source, and copied them to an array of integers?  Q: Aftwards, did you try "array.toString()"?  Q: What did you get?  Where are you "stuck"?

Comment: yes i have got a data like this example [0.{categoryId :1},1.{categoryId :2}] and so on but this is not the result i want. I want the result to be example "1,2,3,4" only the ids in one row. Please check the onbuttonclick function what i have to change there to get the result. i have tried toString on OnButtonClick function i got cannot use toString on type void.

Comment: hello i have made changes and  i have got one question ill update the question please check

Comment: Are you having a result like this? https://i.ibb.co/qC7H2Q2/Screenshot-2022-07-16-092533.png

Comment: yes same as that result but i want only the value "1,2,3,4" in one row, Example hubxCategoryid : [1,2,3,4] this is the type of result i want

Comment: It sounds like you're almost there.  See my example below.  See also: https://www.javatpoint.com/javascript-create-and-download-csv-file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you're generating formArray correctly, your onButtonClick() event handler could do something like this:

```js
let formArray =  [
  {"categoryId" :1},
  {"categoryId" :2}
];
console.log("original js:", formArray)
let ids = [];
formArray.forEach( (element) => {
  ids.push(element.categoryId);
});
console.log("new array:", ids);
let csv = ids.join(",");
console.log("csv:", csv);
```

Comment: thanks its working but i have one question how do i call csv in my hubxcategory formarray

Answer (score 2):

You can use `join`

```
const res = [1,2,3,4].join(',')
```

Comment: how do i call res in my hubxcategory formarray